# How to show welcome message in Wix before prerequisite install?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, prerequisites

I have a WiX installer which installs .Net 4 and SQL as prerequisites. All works fine, but the first thing the user sees on clicking setup.exe is a EULA agreement for .net 4, followed by the list of EULAs for each of the prerequisites. My Wix_Minimal welcome screen only pops up after the prerequisites have finished, when the .msi for my actual application starts.

I would like a welcome message to show right at the start, which explains what is about to happen. Something like "Welcome to the x Install. Setup will now update your computer. please agree to the following license agreements".

How do I get WiX to show a dialog or message box right at the start of the install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the behavior of the bootstrapper you are using. I'd suggest looking into the bootstrapper features (named Burn) in WiX 3.6, which will allow you to do what you are asking.

Note in some cases though you cannot get around this if your bootstrapper has prerequisites and you need to bootstrap the bootstrapper.

Comment: I have Wix 3.5. What bootstrapper does that use?

Comment: Unfortunately WiX 3.5 doesn't have bootstrapper support.

Comment: That would explain why I'm stuck! So I should upgrade to 3.6. Thanks